# Doing a simple excel min calculation without using a loop in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

### The Problem:

So i have, what I thought was, a very basic excel formula that I was trying to replicate in a python data frame. What I'm trying to recreate is the PeriodDraw column. All that is doing is calculating a running value which tells you how far away from the max pl you get before you make a new max. I'm trying to find a way to calculate that column in a data frame without using a loop or in the fastest way possible if I have to loop through it.

Expected output: The PeriodDraw Column from the table below.

---

### What the formulas are doing:

So total PL is the running total. The max column is a running max of the Total PL column and the Diff just takes the diff of the Total PL and the Max column.

In excel, the formula that would go in the second row of the Period draw is  =IF(G2=0,0,MIN(G2,H1)) where G2 = Diff and H column is the PeriodDraw.

So essentially, if the diff is 0 that means the pl is currently at it's max value. If not, then i want to know is the current diff less than my previous  diff value? if so, that's the new min, if not keep the same.

---

Here is the link the spreadsheet if youd like to see the formulas:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lvwIi3ZwLU0Y_6G3fGHII_WvEPU8kPdJ9mUgHUVlBUc/edit?usp=sharing

I've only been able to repeat this using a for loop.

```
+------------+----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+--------+------------+
| TradeCount | Entry Px | Exit Px | Trade PL | Total PL |  Max  |  Diff  | PeriodDraw |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+--------+------------+
|          1 | 0.5057   | 0.6327  |    26656 |    26656 | 26656 |      0 |          0 |
|          2 | 0.66     | 0.6552  |    -1022 |    25634 | 26656 |  -1022 |      -1022 |
|          3 | 0.6577   | 0.6066  |   -10745 |    14889 | 26656 | -11767 |     -11767 |
|          4 | 0.6066   | 0.5682  |     8050 |    22939 | 26656 |  -3717 |     -11767 |
|          5 | 0.5682   | 0.5632  |    -1064 |    21875 | 26656 |  -4781 |     -11767 |
|          6 | 0.5632   | 0.5627  |       91 |    21966 | 26656 |  -4690 |     -11767 |
|          7 | 0.5627   | 0.5657  |      616 |    22582 | 26656 |  -4074 |     -11767 |
|          8 | 0.5876   | 0.5691  |    -3899 |    18683 | 26656 |  -7973 |     -11767 |
|          9 | 0.5527   | 0.5679  |     3178 |    21861 | 26656 |  -4795 |     -11767 |
|         10 | 0.5867   | 0.5777  |    -1904 |    19957 | 26656 |  -6699 |     -11767 |
|         11 | 0.5599   | 0.5597  |      -56 |    19901 | 26656 |  -6755 |     -11767 |
|         12 | 0.5875   | 0.5917  |      868 |    20769 | 26656 |  -5887 |     -11767 |
|         13 | 0.5757   | 0.5615  |    -2996 |    17773 | 26656 |  -8883 |     -11767 |
|         14 | 0.5752   | 0.5545  |    -4361 |    13412 | 26656 | -13244 |     -13244 |
|         15 | 0.5722   | 0.5827  |     2191 |    15603 | 26656 | -11053 |     -13244 |
|         16 | 0.5752   | 0.6528  |    16282 |    31885 | 31885 |      0 |          0 |
|         17 | 0.6511   | 0.6288  |    -4697 |    27188 | 31885 |  -4697 |      -4697 |
|         18 | 0.65     | 0.6487  |     -287 |    26901 | 31885 |  -4984 |      -4984 |
|         19 | 0.5919   | 0.6264  |    -7259 |    19642 | 31885 | -12243 |     -12243 |
|         20 | 0.6264   | 0.6323  |     1225 |    20867 | 31885 | -11018 |     -12243 |
|         21 | 0.6281   | 0.5617  |   -13958 |     6909 | 31885 | -24976 |     -24976 |
+------------+----------+---------+----------+----------+-------+--------+------------+
```

---

### What I've Tried So far:

```
stats_df['Max'] = stats_df['PL_Accum'].cummax()
stats_df['Diff'] = stats_df['PL_Accum'] - stats_df['Max']
df = stats_df.copy().reset_index()
m = []
for i in df.index:
    if df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('PL_Accum')] == df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Max')]:
        m.append(df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Diff')])
    elif i == 0:
        m.append(0)
    else:
        m.append(min(m[i - 1], df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Diff')]))

stats_df['PeriodDraw_Closed'] = m
```

Comment: @ScottBoston 
the expected output is the PeriodDraw column in the table above. I'll make an edit it o make that more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this, I include PD_close for comparison:
I think you are looking for the `cummin` function by groups.

```
df['PD_Close'] = df.groupby(df['Diff'].eq(0).cumsum())['Total PL']\
                   .transform(lambda x: x.cummin())-df['Max']
```

Details:

- We break the dataframe in to groups defined by column Diff equals to 0.  How, we use `eq` to set rows where diff is zero an then we use cumsum to increment a counter everytime Diff equals to zero.
- Next, we use that counter as a way to group the dataframe into parts
  so we can calculate local minimums.  Using `cummin` we can keep a
  running tally of the lowest value found in each group for Total PL.
- Lastly, we subtract Max from that local minimum in each group.

If you run each little part of that statement starting from what is inside the groupby then working your out, you see the statement take shape.

Output:

```
     TradeCount  Entry Px  Exit Px  Trade PL  Total PL    Max   Diff  PeriodDraw  PD_close
0             1    0.5057   0.6327     26656     26656  26656      0           0         0
1             2    0.6600   0.6552     -1022     25634  26656  -1022       -1022     -1022
2             3    0.6577   0.6066    -10745     14889  26656 -11767      -11767    -11767
3             4    0.6066   0.5682      8050     22939  26656  -3717      -11767    -11767
4             5    0.5682   0.5632     -1064     21875  26656  -4781      -11767    -11767
5             6    0.5632   0.5627        91     21966  26656  -4690      -11767    -11767
6             7    0.5627   0.5657       616     22582  26656  -4074      -11767    -11767
7             8    0.5876   0.5691     -3899     18683  26656  -7973      -11767    -11767
8             9    0.5527   0.5679      3178     21861  26656  -4795      -11767    -11767
9            10    0.5867   0.5777     -1904     19957  26656  -6699      -11767    -11767
10           11    0.5599   0.5597       -56     19901  26656  -6755      -11767    -11767
11           12    0.5875   0.5917       868     20769  26656  -5887      -11767    -11767
12           13    0.5757   0.5615     -2996     17773  26656  -8883      -11767    -11767
13           14    0.5752   0.5545     -4361     13412  26656 -13244      -13244    -13244
14           15    0.5722   0.5827      2191     15603  26656 -11053      -13244    -13244
15           16    0.5752   0.6528     16282     31885  31885      0           0         0
16           17    0.6511   0.6288     -4697     27188  31885  -4697       -4697     -4697
17           18    0.6500   0.6487      -287     26901  31885  -4984       -4984     -4984
18           19    0.5919   0.6264     -7259     19642  31885 -12243      -12243    -12243
19           20    0.6264   0.6323      1225     20867  31885 -11018      -12243    -12243
20           21    0.6281   0.5617    -13958      6909  31885 -24976      -24976    -24976
21           22    0.5589   0.6311    -15176     -8267  31885 -40152      -40152    -40152
22           23    0.6311   0.7148     17563      9296  31885 -22589      -40152    -40152
23           24    0.6925   0.6867      1204     10500  31885 -21385      -40152    -40152
24           25    0.6867   0.6874       133     10633  31885 -21252      -40152    -40152
25           26    0.6874   0.6260     12880     23513  31885  -8372      -40152    -40152
26           27    0.6260   0.7252     20818     44331  44331      0           0         0
27           28    0.7252   0.7177      1561     45892  45892      0           0         0
28           29    0.7092   0.7241      3115     49007  49007      0           0         0
29           30    0.7241   0.7303     -1316     47691  49007  -1316       -1316     -1316
..          ...       ...      ...       ...       ...    ...    ...         ...       ...
99          100    1.2640   1.2666      -560     43015  63273 -20258      -75040    -75040
100         101    1.2666   1.3050      8050     51065  63273 -12208      -75040    -75040
101         102    1.3222   1.3075     -3101     47964  63273 -15309      -75040    -75040
102         103    1.2927   1.3443    -10850     37114  63273 -26159      -75040    -75040
103         104    1.3458   1.3452      -140     36974  63273 -26299      -75040    -75040
104         105    1.3502   1.3484      -392     36582  63273 -26691      -75040    -75040
105         106    1.3578   1.4015      9163     45745  63273 -17528      -75040    -75040
106         107    1.4119   1.3982     -2891     42854  63273 -20419      -75040    -75040
107         108    1.4098   1.3950     -3122     39732  63273 -23541      -75040    -75040
108         109    1.3950   1.2162     37534     77266  77266      0           0         0
109         110    1.2236   1.2227       175     77441  77441      0           0         0
110         111    1.2317   1.2749     -9086     68355  77441  -9086       -9086     -9086
111         112    1.2749   1.3335     12292     80647  80647      0           0         0
112         113    1.3233   1.2642    -12425     68222  80647 -12425      -12425    -12425
113         114    1.2343   1.1587     15862     84084  84084      0           0         0
114         115    1.1655   1.1427      4774     88858  88858      0           0         0
115         116    1.1226   1.0950     -5810     83048  88858  -5810       -5810     -5810
116         117    1.0950   1.0927       469     83517  88858  -5341       -5810     -5810
117         118    1.0676   1.0243      9079     92596  92596      0           0         0
118         119    0.9734   1.0088     -7448     85148  92596  -7448       -7448     -7448
119         120    1.0327   1.0484      3283     88431  92596  -4165       -7448     -7448
120         121    1.0484   1.0769     -5999     82432  92596 -10164      -10164    -10164
121         122    1.0794   1.0766      -602     81830  92596 -10766      -10766    -10766
122         123    1.0766   1.0764        28     81858  92596 -10738      -10766    -10766
123         124    1.0794   1.0817       469     82327  92596 -10269      -10766    -10766
124         125    1.0817   1.0697      2506     84833  92596  -7763      -10766    -10766
125         126    1.0697   1.1097     -8414     76419  92596 -16177      -16177    -16177
126         127    1.1097   1.1247      3136     79555  92596 -13041      -16177    -16177
127         128    1.1462   1.1497       721     80276  92596 -12320      -16177    -16177
128         129    1.1497   1.1517      -434     79842  92596 -12754      -16177    -16177
```

Comment: Awesome! Is this faster than using a loop?

Comment: wow - this shaves off .3 seconds per run. thank you so much! For educational purposes do you mind explaining what your code is doing? Def will leave you some love on the linkedin

Comment: This should be much faster than looping because we are using vectorized operations on a pandas dataframe.   You are taking advantage of the sequential location in memory calculations are done all in one pass.